# 19 out of 24 words of BIP39 passphrase (brute-force last 5?)

Tags: mining-hardware, hash, hashpower, asic, asic-resistance

I have managed to lose 5 words of my 24 word Ledger Nano S recovery phrase. I have words 1-19 but I am missing words 20-24. I have significant holdings on the wallet so would very much like to recover it if possible. The passphrase is a BIP39 mnemonic (see https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki). I have the bitcoin and ethereum public addresses for this mnemonic. I am wondering if it's feasible to brute force the passphrase.

Each word is 11 bits (2^11 = 2048 possible words). The last (24th) word of the passphrase is of the following form [3 random bits][8 bit checksum]. Therefore I only have to check 2^(55 - 8) = 2^47 = 1.4x10^14 combinations. I would have to compute SHA-512-HMAC with an iteration count of 2048. As far as I understand, that means I'd have to compute 1.4*10^14 * 2048 = 2.87*10^17 hashes in total.

Is there any hardware out there designed for this? I am aware of ASICs that compute sha-256 hashes but not sha-512 hashes. Perhaps I could tweak one to work with sha-512 since they are very similar.

Assuming a fairly typical ASIC hashrate of 1TH/s (10^12 hashes per second), I could exhaust the search space in 2.87*10^5 = 287000 seconds = 3.3 days. I'd probably get there sooner, of course (expected 1.65 days). Time is not something I am worried about. Even if I have to wait months, I don't mind - so if I can get 10GH/s at a reasonable price, that would be great.

I would really appreciate any help/information you could provide to help me out and make sure I haven't missed anything. I could also use GPUs for this (I calculate I can run them at roughly $1/10TH - so it would cost me $28.7k to exhaust the search space, which I will do if there are no cheaper options).

Many thanks, James

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/87326/208